# USB-to-USB transfer without admin rights?

Tags: usb

Are there USB-to-USB transfer cables for Windows 7 which don't require software installation with admin rights? How can I know which one would be suitable? Does http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-to-get-an-easy-transfer-cable mean that everything that's called "Easy Transfer" is not suitable, if you don't have admin rights?

I'd like to quickly exchange data between computers which cannot be connected by network. Also I don't have admin rights on one of the computers.

Comment: And why is it that a USB connection is feasible where a network connection isn't?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly no.  You need a driver to communicate with USB, and drivers can only be installed by admin.

Comment: There are USB flash drives that do not need installation. This might be your only option. Creating a network between 2 pc's is an administrative task, and requires installation before it is possible. Its not the cable that requires administrative privileges. Its the communicating with the other pc that initiates this.

Comment: @DanielB: I haven't checked thoroughly. But the computer without admin rights is already connected to the internet, so there is no available LAN slot. There is no Wifi either. The other computer maybe doesn't have a network card (need to check). Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I can swap USB sticks between computers, so I thought there would be something that includes software in the hardware and simplifys this transfer.

Comment: Trying to circumvent someone else's security settings? I think an admin of that computer, on which you `don't have admin rights`, made it so for good reason.

Comment: @Gerenuk USB sticks don't (typically) include software. They rely upon generic drivers built-in to Windows. Otherwise, you would need to have Administrator permissions to install the drivers for each new stick.

Comment: If your computer is connected to the Internet, it's also connected to the LAN. Check if your other computer has a network card (which, if you didn't take it out, it probably will have) and wire them up to the same network. Then you can share the files between them through your preferred method (FTP, Windows share...)

Comment: After reading this question, I've totally lost my concept of USB. I was thinking, it is (electrically) impossible to connect two PC's through USB ports by a single cable. Both the PC's will put +5V DC on the line - how to find out who is master? who is slave? Do we need an electronics in between for regulating the line?